# Elasticsearch - Compare score over different queries

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I have a parent-child-query and depending on how good my children match I have three different actions to do. The documents all have roughly the same same size so right now I do it by just comparing the `score`. I noticed that the score is always between 0 and 10 and I set my thresholds at `1.5` and `3.0`. But I've read multiple times that comparing scores over multiple queries will not work. 
My current query looks like that

```
var result = _client.Search<DataTypes.MyParent>(s => s
    .Query(q => q
        .HasChild<DataTypes.MyChild>(c => c
            .ScoreMode(ChildScoreMode.Sum)
            .Query(qq => qq
                .CommonTerms(ct => ct
                    .Field(f => f.Content)
                    .Query(content)
                )
            )
            .InnerHits()
        )
    )
).Hits;

var bestResult = result.FirstOrDefault();


if (bestResult.IsNotNull())
{
    if (bestResult.Score < 1.5) { ... }
    else if (bestResult.Score < 3.0) { ... }
    else { ... }
}
```

I guess as soon as my parents get more children or have different amounts of children this approach won't work anymore since I sum the children's scores up. 
I thought about using `MinimumShouldMatch` but then i'll need to send the same query twice.

So what is the correct way of seeing how good the best match is?

---

*edit*

#### What's the underlying problem you're trying to solve?

In my elastic index I have different answers with multiple questions. When the user enters a new question my system needs to find the best matching questions and from these it needs to find an answer. Now there can be three cases:

1. The system finds a very relevant answer because many questions of that answer match the new question. Then it should automatically answer that question.
2. The system finds an answer but it is not confident enough to answer the question. Then it should just propose that answer but not directly send it.
3. The system does not find an answer at all or is so unconfined with the result that it won't do anything. Maybe the question asked simply has no answer in my system.

In order to see which case I am in, I compare the score of the answer to some magic threshholds. But obviously this is no perfect solution. Elastics score simply is not made for this operation.

So my question is: How can I know how confident elastic is with the results?

Comment: What's the underlying problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: updated the question

Comment: To make it more motivating for people to help you, you can add something like this as a first line: * string content="What is the distance between earth and sun ?"; * And give a bunch of additional examples questions and answers.

Comment: To make even more motivating: Show the content of your eastic search index.

Answer (score 0):

In short term, if index content is roughly the same, these scores will be the same (for queries with the same structure), and for your case I don't see another solution without this comparison. But scores depend on term frequencies and document frequencies. And if you add more documents or change the content of existing docs, it will impact your scores. So, you may need adjust these thresholds periodically.

Comment: Not the answer I hoped for but at least something

Comment: If it doesn't answer your question, feel free to ask what is missing.